# How can i access the elements from multi dimensional json array (in SQL Server)

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional JSON array, I am accessing the JSON array in SQL Server and using 'OPENJSON' to convert JSON data to SQL. I am currently facing problem in fetching the data from multidimensional array

```
Declare @Json nvarchar(max)

Set @Json= '[{
    "id": 0,
    "healthandSafety": "true",
    "estimationCost": "7878",
    "comments": "\"Comments\"",
    "image": [{
        "imageData": "1"
    }, {
        "imageData": "2"
    }, {
        "imageData": "3"
    }, {
        "imageData": "4"
    }, {
        "imageData": "5"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "healthandSafety": "false",
    "estimationCost": "90",
    "comments": "\"89089\"",
    "image": [{
        "imageData": "6"
    }, {
        "imageData": "7"
    }, {
        "imageData": "8"
    }, {
        "imageData": "9"
    }, {
        "imageData": "10"
    }, {
        "imageData": "11"
    }]
}]'

Select ImageJsonFile from OPENJSON (@Json) with (ImageJsonFile nvarchar(max) '$.image[0].imageData')
```

When I tried the above code I obtained the following output:

```
ImageJsonFile
1
6
```

The output what I am expecting :

```
ImageJsonFile
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define query path:

```
Select * from OPENJSON (@Json,'$[0].image') with (ImageJsonFile nvarchar(max) '$.imageData')
```

Comment: That's how you do it! Thanks Piotr, i learned something here. :)

Answer (score 2):

You've got an answer already, so this is just to add some more details:

The following will bring back all data from your *multi dimensional array*, not just one array index you'd have to specify explictly.

```
DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'[{
    "id": 0,
    "healthandSafety": "true",
    "estimationCost": "7878",
    "comments": "\"Comments\"",
    "image": [{
        "imageData": "1"
    }, {
        "imageData": "2"
    }, {
        "imageData": "3"
    }, {
        "imageData": "4"
    }, {
        "imageData": "5"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "healthandSafety": "false",
    "estimationCost": "90",
    "comments": "\"89089\"",
    "image": [{
        "imageData": "6"
    }, {
        "imageData": "7"
    }, {
        "imageData": "8"
    }, {
        "imageData": "9"
    }, {
        "imageData": "10"
    }, {
        "imageData": "11"
    }]
}]';
```

--The query

```
SELECT A.id
      ,A.healthandSafety
      ,A.estimationCost
      ,A.comments
      ,B.imageData 
FROM OPENJSON(@Json)
WITH(id INT
    ,healthandSafety BIT
    ,estimationCost INT
    ,comments NVARCHAR(1000)
    ,[image] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON ) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.[image])
WITH(imageData INT) B;
```

The result

```
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| id | healthandSafety | estimationCost | comments | imageData |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 0  | 1               | 7878           | Comments | 1         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 0  | 1               | 7878           | Comments | 2         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 0  | 1               | 7878           | Comments | 3         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 0  | 1               | 7878           | Comments | 4         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 0  | 1               | 7878           | Comments | 5         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 0               | 90             | 89089    | 6         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 0               | 90             | 89089    | 7         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 0               | 90             | 89089    | 8         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 0               | 90             | 89089    | 9         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 0               | 90             | 89089    | 10        |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 0               | 90             | 89089    | 11        |
+----+-----------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
```

The idea in short:

We use the first `OPENJSON` to get the elements of the first level. The `WITH` clause will name all elements and return the `[image]` with `NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON`. This allows to use another `OPENJSON` to read the numbers from `imageData`, your nested dimension, while the `id`-column is the grouping key.